# AngularJS toggle divs visibility through button

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have a multiple sets of two divs and a button for each per page. The two divs contains alternating content that the button should handle switching visibility. I can't seem to think of an Angular solution that can be extensible to multiple separate instances in the page (my mind keeps wanting to get it done in JQuery).

[I have created a JSFiddle example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/AJGiliana/XyW6v/2/)

You will see two divs `p_table` class with `<span class="trigger">A</span>`. The trigger should alternate the two p_table inside their parent div `p_container`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The key for how you are doing it is with ng-class, you can also do it with ng-show/ng-hide. Both implementations require no javascript, just a controller scope.

NG-CLASS: Choose a class based on a variable, which toggles on trigger click.

```
<div class="p_container">
  <p class="p_table" ng-class="{hidden:!show,chaldean:show}">This is actual content</p>
  <p class="p_table" ng-class="{hidden:show,chaldean:!show}">This is transliterated content</p> 
  <span class="trigger" ng-click="show=!show">A</span>
</div>
```

NG-SHOW/NG-HIDE: Show  or hide on variable. This is the typical way of doing it.

```
<div class="p_container">
  <p class="p_table" ng-show="show">This is actual content</p>
  <p class="p_table" ng-hide="!show">This is transliterated content</p> 
  <span class="trigger" ng-click="show=!show">A</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the ask but appreciate if you can add a jsfiddle for this. Reason is I am unable to see it working may be due to some issues.

Comment: In the answer, there is some code that refers to "chaldean" I assumed it was a variable name, but I cant see it in the original question. Can someone elaborate on what this is for?

Comment: Look at the poster's JSFiddle link. It is the class name he used in his example. So yes, it is in the original question, if not a little obscured. :)

Comment: You have a bug in your NG-SHOW/NG-HIDE example.
ng-show="show" does exactly the same as ng-hide="!show" 
Either use ng-show="show" and ng-hide="show" or use ng-show="!show" in stead of ng-hide.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it, using `ngHide` and a tiny toggle function. Working demo [Here](http://codepen.io/chrisN/pen/XdBqKE).  I hope this helps

**My HTML Markup**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div id="filter-row">
                <span
                    id="toggle-filter"
                    ng-click="toggleFilter()">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
                </span>

                <div class="hiddenDiv" ng-hide="toggle">
                    <p>I am the hidden Div!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**My AngularJS Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller ("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.toggle = true;
  $scope.toggleFilter = function() {
       $scope.toggle = $scope.toggle === false ? true : false;
  }
}]);
```

Comment: The function body can be simplified to `$scope.toggle = $scope.toggle === false;`

Comment: even can be more  simplified with 
$scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;