# Multiple Radio Buttons on select attach div with down arrow as background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have list of inputs of type radios, these drop downs provide sort functionality on data set based on select. Initially, the select provides sorting on ascending order. To provide both sorts of sorting (ascending & descending ) , on select  of radio would like to display a down arrow image initially & sort data in ascending  and then when the user clicks the arrow it will turn as up arrow image and sorts data in descending order. And when the user clicks the other radio the arrow will be removed from previously selected radio and added to current selected radio.

Here is the HTML

```
<ul>
<li> <input type="radio" id="btn_Value" name="btn_Sort" value="Value" ng-model="sortType" ng-click="sortChartData('Value')"  />&#09;&#09;&#09;Value</li>
<li>  <input type="radio" id="btn_ScoreSort" name="btn_Sort"  value="Score"  ng-Model="sortType" ng-click="sortChartData('Score')"  />&#09;&#09;&#09;Score</li>
<li>  <input type="radio" id="btn_Quartile" name="btn_Sort" ng-Model="sortType" ng-click="sortChartData('Quartile')" value="Quartile" />&#09;&#09;&#09;Quartile</li>
</ul>
```

I can attach a div next to each li and set property display none in CSS class and down arrow CSS class and remove the display:none property and add jquery event handler on click. Here is the new HTML.

```
  <ul>
  <li> <input type="radio" id="btn_Value" name="btn_Sort" value="Value" ng-model="sortType" ng-click="sortChartData('Value')"  />&#09;&#09;&#09;Value<div class="hide ascSort"></div></li>
<li>  <input type="radio" id="btn_ScoreSort" name="btn_Sort"  value="Score"  ng-Model="sortType" ng-click="sortChartData('Score')"  />&#09;&#09;&#09;Score</li>
<li>  <input type="radio" id="btn_Quartile" name="btn_Sort" ng-Model="sortType" ng-click="sortChartData('Quartile')" value="Quartile" />&#09;&#09;&#09;Quartile</li>
</ul>
```

But, this seems to me as not that efficient way. Can anyone suggest any other approaches ?

Comment: I think that is just a fine way of doing it. Better to use `span` (inline).

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tags show you are using jQuery.  You can simply use the `.hide()` and `.show()` methods of a jQuery element.  Something like:

```
$("#sortArrowAsc").show();
$("#sortArrowDesc").hide();
```

You can start with the `display: none` style and use these commands to `.toggle()` as well:

```
$("#sortArrowAsc").toggle();
$("#sortArrowDesc").toggle();
```

EDIT:
From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895849/angularjs-toggle-divs-visibility-through-button) link, you could try a variable like `show` that you toggle on click:

```
<div class="yourRadioContainer">
  <span class="someUp" ng-show="show"><img src='uparrow.png' /></span>
  <span class="someDown" ng-hide="!show"><img src='downarrow.png' /></span> 
  <span class="trigger" ng-click="show=!show">Radio Asc</span>
  <span class="trigger" ng-click="show=!show">Radio Desc</span>
</div>
```

The two triggers would act the same you are simply toggling from one state to the other.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Actually, I am using AngularJs.

Comment: Does that mean that you're *not* using jQuery? Because, if so, you should remove the [tag:jquery] tag from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Figured a solution.

```
<ul id="sort">
<li> <input type="radio" id="btn_Value" name="btn_Sort" value="Value" ng-model="sortType" ng-click="sortChartData('Value')"  />&#09;&#09;&#09;Value<span id="sortValue" class="descSort" ng-if="valueSortType" ng-click="changeSortType($event)"></span></li>
<li>  <input type="radio" id="btn_ScoreSort" name="btn_Sort"  value="Score"  ng-Model="sortType" ng-click="sortChartData('Score')"  />&#09;&#09;&#09;Score<span id="sortScore" class="descSort" ng-if="scoreSortType" ng-click="changeSortType($event)"></span></li>
<li>  <input type="radio" id="btn_Quartile" name="btn_Sort" ng-Model="sortType" ng-click="sortChartData('Quartile')" value="Quartile" />&#09;&#09;&#09;Quartile<span id="sortQt" class="descSort" ng-if="qtSortType" ng-click="changeSortType($event)"></span></li>
</ul>
```

In the HTML  **ng-if="valueSortType"** gets updated when ever the user selects the radio to true.

Event Handler:

```
$scope.changeSortType = function (event) {
    var elem = event.target;
    var cssClass = elem.getAttribute('class');
    if (cssClass.indexOf("ascSort") > -1) {
        $(elem).removeClass('ascSort');
        $(elem).addClass('descSort');
        $scope.sortOrder = "desc";
    }
    if (cssClass.indexOf("descSort") > -1) {
        $(elem).removeClass('descSort');
        $(elem).addClass('ascSort');
        $scope.sortOrder = "asc";
    }
    $scope.$watch("sortOder", function () {
        $scope.sortChartData($scope.sortType);
    });
};
```