# ng-class and ng-click not working together

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with ng-class and ng-click together. I want to add class to div when button click, but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
    <header>
    <div id="headerContainer">
        <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle</button>
    </div>
</header>

<nav ng-class="{'myClassName' : toggle}"></nav>
```

What's weird? When I add ng-class to my button it's toggling class on button, but my `<nav>` still don't get the class:

```
<button ng-click="toggle = !toggle" ng-class="{'myClassName' : toggle}">Toggle</button>
```

How to make it work and why it doesn't work properly?

Comment: Can you show your controller?.

Comment: toggle = !toggle wont modify $scope.toggle in the controller. You need to write a controller method to modify $scope.toggle. The reason behind is that the scope you are accessing is not $scope.toggle but a child of it. To modify the $scope.toggle, you can only do that in the controller.

Comment: show us more code , ? controller ?

Comment: show us your myClassName ? Perhaps it is setting the class, but the css does not display as expected?

Comment: There's no controller. I wanted to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895849/angularjs-toggle-divs-visibility-through-button)

Comment: @delco Works fine for me.. [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4ONw5e88DSITZsCpyDo?p=preview)

Comment: If you can, create a plnkr of your problem, your example looks good. It must be a details hidden somewhere.

Comment: @ShyA, yes, but I want to toggle class on <nav>, not button

Comment: @delco check now [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4ONw5e88DSITZsCpyDo?p=preview)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below an example of a working code. Please see @Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant for as why your snippet doesn't work.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope' , function($scope) {
  $scope.toggle = false;

  $scope.changeToggle = function(){
    $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
  }
  
}])
```

```html
<style>
.myClass{
  color: red;
}
</style>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="changeToggle()" ng-class="{'myClass' : toggle}">Toggle</button>
</div>
  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your solution was the best for me. Thank you all, guys!

Answer (score 1):

toggle = !toggle wont modify $scope.toggle in the controller.

You need to write a controller method to modify $scope.toggle.

The reason behind is that the scope you are accessing is not $scope.toggle but a child of it. To modify the $scope.toggle, you can only do that in the controller

Comment: You are assuming he is using nested scopes. I think you're right, but your statement comes out as the truth in any case - which is it not always.

Answer (score 1):

It has been mentioned before, but *if* your `toggle` variable is declared in another scope (deeper nested) then you won't be able to access it from the nav menu.

There are two ways around this. Either you can add the variable in the controller (some people suggest this) as it will make the variable known at the top level and accessible to all child scopes, or you can simple initialize/hoist it on the element of your outer controller by using `ng-init`.

It really is hard to help when you only post part of your setup, since the error/problem does not lie in the stuff you posted but in what was not posted :)

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you meant on doing?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <header>
    <div id="headerContainer">
      <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle</button>
    </div>
  </header>

  <nav ng-class="myClassName {{toggle}}"></nav>

</div>
```